# What's the right tool from Google Cloud Platform to obtain data from a Web Service periodically?

Tags: rest, web-services, google-cloud-platform

I'm new to GCP and trying to understand if there's a tool to obtain periodically data from an external Web Service to save the obtained data in Bigtable using Dataflow...

Comment: This might be of interest: https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/04/scheduling-dataflow-pipelines-using-app-engine-cron-service-or-cloud-functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way in GCP to schedule periodic jobs is to use [App Engine cron jobs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml). The platform, at the time or interval you defined, will call the url you specified.

From that url handler, you can call the Web Service you want to retrieve data from and launch a Dataflow job to process that data and [write to BigTable](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/dataflow-hbase#writing).

Dan Cornilescu in comments provided a useful [link](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/04/scheduling-dataflow-pipelines-using-app-engine-cron-service-or-cloud-functions) to achieve this. Note that, although it's ~2years old, the information provided there still holds true, in particular the fact that you'll need to use App Engine Flexible environment to launch your Dataflow job. Although App Engine Standard Java8 release remove restrictions on JRE classes, Dataflow SDK is still not supported on Standard environment.